# ODBC in Go doesn't Identify the type of returned query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, go, odbc

I've started working with DB connections using ODBC (before, I used direct connect with a given connection string). I managed to connect to the DB and execute queries successfully, but I noticed that I can't identify the type that returns from the query.

For example (with mssql/sqlserver): After I run a count query (select count(*) from MY_TABLE) I check the type of the returned value (not showing here but I do check errors, this is just to give a perspective):

```
rows, _ := Db.Query(queryStatement)
colsType, _ := rows.ColumnTypes()
name := colsType[i].ScanType().Name()
switch name {
case "int64":
    //do something..
case "int32":
    //do something..
case "int16":
    //do something..
case "Time":
    //do something..
case "float64":
    //do something..
case "bool":
    //do something..
case "string":
    //do something..
default:
    //do something..
```

The type should return as int64/32/16 (in my case it's 64) since count returns a numeric value.

When I run this with a direct DB connection (aka connection string), it does recognize the type.
But when I run this with ODBC connection, it doesn't recognize it (the **name** variable would be populated "").

I made sure that I'm communicating with the same DB (whenever I connect directly or with ODBC)

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: `select count(*) from MY_TABLE` has an unnamed column, you want `select count(*) as SomeColumnNameHere from MY_TABLE`

Comment: Tried it out, still get the same issue. Does it work for you? If so perhaps seeing an implementation might help me understand what I'm mising

Comment: Have you tried just printing out the value of `name`. I'd guess it will be `interface{}` (as the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#ColumnType.ScanType) say "If a driver does not support this property ScanType will return the type of an empty interface"). We don't know what driver you are using, but I don't think `alexbrainman/odbc` [supports ScanType](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/pull/114).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood what you meant by the value of `name`. the Name() function returns a string value to the `name` variable. The weird thing though is that you're right about the empty interface{} but I do get a value (aka not an empty interface{}), It just doesn't manage to identify the type of it for some reason

Comment: Drivers provide differing levels of functionality, some do not implement  [RowsColumnTypeScanType](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver@go1.21.5#RowsColumnTypeScanType) and, in that case, `ColumnTypes()` will always return [`reflect.TypeOf(new(any)).Elem()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=3214). That's what appears to be happening here (you have not confirmed what driver you are using; however `alexbrainman/odbc` is the only one I know, and I don't believe it implements `RowsColumnTypeScanType`).

Comment: Yes I'm using `alexbrainman/odbc`. And yes it seems to be the case. I'll need to find a way around it in the code. Thank you all for the help!